# How to retrieve values from different disjointed cells in excel using Office.JS

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to retrieve values from disjointed cells (**RangeAreas**) in an Excel web add-in but I'm struggling to figure out how to do so. In contiguous cells, I can use the *"values"* property of the **Range** class as follows:

```
let currentWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
let foundRange = currentWorksheet.getRange("A1:A5").load("values");

return context.sync().then(function () {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(foundRange.values));
});
```

How can I do that with disjointed cells on the **RangeAreas** class? I can't find this documented anywhere. This is my code to get a **RangeAreas** of disjointed cells and where I can successfully get their *"address"*, but how can I get their *"value"*?

```
let currentWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet(); // Get active worksheet
let foundRangeAreas = currentWorksheet.findAll("My Keyword", { completeMatch: false, matchCase: false });

foundRangeAreas.load("address");

return context.sync().then(function () {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(foundRangeAreas.address));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `RangeAreas.areas` property which returns a collection of rectangular ranges and load values for each range:

```
foundRangeAreas.load("areas/values");
```

For more information, check: [Excel Range Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangeareas?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-rangeareas-areas-member)

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. I ran foundRangeAreas.load("areas"), followed by a context.sync(), after which I can access the data using foundRangeAreas.areas.items